# How to debug ref class properties in Windows store app (C++)

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

When debugging Windows store app with Visual studio 2013, I can't seem to evaluate ref class properties in Watch and Immediate Window.

eg)

```
_inputGrid = ref new XEditTransform();
_inputGrid->HorizontalAlignment = Windows::UI::Xaml::HorizontalAlignment::Left;
_inputGrid->VerticalAlignment = Windows::UI::Xaml::VerticalAlignment::Top;
```

And I want to find the value of _inputGrid->VerticalAlignment I get following errors in the Watch Window.

```
_inputGrid->VerticalAlignment::get()    name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name 
_inputGrid->VerticalAlignment           Implicit function evaluation of properties is not supported.
```

Does anyone know how to debug with ref class properties? I'm getting tired of adding debug code snippets everytime I want to check the property.

Comment: Microsoft still has a *lot* of work to do on the debugger to make it look like a property at runtime as well.  Bit of a chicken-and-egg problem, I doubt that WinRT can ever truly be a success until it gets easy to debug and diagnose, but they probably won't spend the massive resources on the debugger until it is a success.